# Merge vim system buffers

Tags: unix, vim, buffer, copy-paste

Is it possible to to do the following:

```
Terminal1: vim f1.txt
su someuser
Terminal2: vim f2.txt
```

I want to copy text from f1 in Termial1 as user A to f2 in Terminal2 as user someuser. I am using system buffer using "+y "+p commands it works great if I am with the same user.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this without issue.  The only difference is that I used "+gP instead of "+p.
Also, gave it a whirl in gvim without problem using point/click edit > copy  and edit > paste.

So, maybe try "+gP or gvim?

Comment: I don't use gvim... I wonder if there is solution using "+y and "+p?

Comment: "+gP isn't a gvim specific command.  See :help gP, :help p, :help P for differences.  It is really just cursor placement.  So, yes "+y "+p work fine too...I'm doing it from visual mode (Shift-V for line select, for example) and it works fine using gnome terminal.  Maybe the "+y or "+p have been remapped or not making it to your registry somehow, but it should work fine for you.